# Parsing a symbolic expression that includes user-defined functions in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have some equations that call other functions. I want to write this symbolically, is it possible to do this in Sympy?

Here's an simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
x = sp.Symbol('x')
omega = sp.Function('omega')(x ** 2)

eq_1 = sp.sympify("omega(x)")
```

eq_1 is calling function omega with argument x , returning x**2. Any ideas on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = sp.Symbol('x')
omega = sp.Lambda(x, x**2)
eq_1 = sp.sympify("omega(x)", locals={"omega": omega})
```

The key points:

- Lambda is a way to create a SymPy function which performs a specific operation
- `locals` is a parameter of `sympify` which links substrings of the input, such as "omega", to the SymPy objects you created. Without it, `sympify` will only link built-in functions like `exp` or `sin`, but it will not be guessing whether "omega" in the input really means your function, or an unrelated letter omega.