# Defining a function in SymPy that takes a list as argument

Tags: python, sympy, custom-function

I'm currently building a "formula editor" in a GUI application in python.
I use sympy to parse and check the validity of the typed formula, based on a dictionary of `subs`. No problem with that.

Sometimes, user will need to type "complex" formulae with redundant parameters.
See this example below:

```
Array([0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 1.1])[Mod(p-1, 4)]
```

The list `[0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 1.1]` is chosen by the user and can be of any length. Given the value of `p` variable, il will result in one of the four elements of the list. The number `4` is obviously `len([0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 1.1]`.
The user can easily mistype the formula...

Rather, I would like to create my own function, eg. `userlist()`, taking the list as argument and behaving as needed.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306092/parsing-a-symbolic-expression-that-includes-user-defined-functions-in-sympy) which helped me start with functions taking numbers as argument. It did not help me much with arguments which are lists.

Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT:**
In a nutshell, I need to define `userlist()` in some way so that this line

```
parse_expr("userlist(p, [8, 4, 6, 7])").evalf(subs={'p': 10})
```

returns the `Mod(p-1, len(list))`th element of the list (here the 2nd element: `4`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking but maybe this helps:

```
In [75]: A = IndexedBase('A')

In [76]: A[Mod(p-1, 4)]
Out[76]: A[Mod(p + 3, 4)]

In [77]: f = lambdify((p, A), A[Mod(p-1, 4)])

In [78]: f(2, [3, 5, 6, 7])
Out[78]: 5
```

Comment: thank you Oscar Benjamin. This is a good start as I didn't know about `IndexedBase`. I still need to replace `4` by `len(A)` to be more flexible. Furthemore my firsts test failed in parsing a string expression. I edited my question; hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Finally, I used this : `'userlist': lambda lst, p: Array(lst)[Mod((p - 1), len(lst))]` as `local_dict` so that the expression can be evaluated later (given a value for `p`)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I see your updated question. I'm still not sure I fully understand but I expect that this example will be more helpful:

```
In [7]: parse_expr("userlist(p, [8, 4, 6, 7])", {'userlist': lambda a, b: print(a, b)})
p [8, 4, 6, 7]
```

The `lambda` function here can be any Python function you want to use and it will receive the parsed list as an argument so it can call `len` etc.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you so much. So simple now I see it.